# com.mongodb.MongoException: invalid operator: $or

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to run a query, which returns all elements of a collection, in which

1. the fields `wasProposed` and `markedByUser` are true and
2. the field `recipientEmail` is either `email1@example.com` or `email2@example.com`.

In my Java code, I create a `BasicDBObject`, whose `toString` returns this:

```
{ 
    "wasProposed" : true , 
    "recipientEmail" : 
    { 
        "$or" : 
            [ 
                { "recipientEmail" : "email1@example.com" } , 
                { "recipientEmail" : "email2@example.com" }
            ]
    }, 
    "markedByUser" : true
}
```

When I run this query (`rcoll.find(query).sort(sortclause).limit(ITEMS_TO_SHOW)`), I get the error `com.mongodb.MongoException: invalid operator: $or`.

How can I modify the query above in order to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably cleaner to use [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) here instead of an `$or`:

```js
{ 
    "wasProposed" : true , 
    "recipientEmail" : { "$in" : ["email1@example.com", "email2@example.com"] },
    "markedByUser" : true
}
```